# How to use a theorem with a match pattern

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

Basically, I have a function, and a theorem about some properties of this function.

The function has the following signature :

```
Fixpoint compute_solution (s : list nat) : (option list nat) := 
...=> None
...=> Some l
```

The theorem  is :

```
Theorem solution_is_correct:
  forall (s : list nat), length s = 9 * 9 ->
       match compute_solution s with
         None => forall s1, length s1 = 9 *9  -> ~ nice_property s1
       | Some s1 => nice_property s1
       end.
```

Now, when I try to prove an additional theorem , I end up in the following situation :

```
s: list nat
Hs: length s = 9 * 9
prem: list nat
sol: compute_solution s = Some prem
...
================================
nice_property prem
```

How can I make use of solution_is_correct to prove the goal ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
pose proof (solution_is_correct s Hs) as Tmp.
rewrite sol in Tmp.
```

But I'd rather rework the theorem to be more usable, eg

```
thm1 : forall s l, ... -> compute_solution s = Some l -> nice_property l
thm2 : forall s, ... -> compute_solution s = None -> ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I works. Just a last assumption step proved the goal.